# Module to play/pause/... videos with python

Tags: python, video, macos

In python I am looking for a python module that I can use to play videos. That module should allow to

- play videos as you could play them with e.g. `mplayer`
- pause them
- stop them
- make them fullscreen
- seek the current position
- set the position.

Alternatively I tried to have run `mplayer` run in `subprocess`, but this does not catch the status line of `mplayer` to see where the video is at the moment.

It must work on MacOS.

I want to write a small program to watch videos, which I can stop at any time, and the program saves the position, so it can resume from that position the next time (without having to remember a scene where   I stopped, without me forwarding to some timestamp etc)